# How can I find out if Stack Overflow has a community for PLX, Google SQL or Dremel SQL users?

Tags: discussion

How can I find out if Stack Overflow has a community for PLX users using Dremel SQL or Google SQL?

Comment: Go search the tags. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plx or combinations of whatever plx stands for.

Comment: You could also check for relevant chat rooms https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=active, though I think you need 20 rep to participate. Depends what you mean by, and are looking for in, a "community."

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I already did several searches.

These technologies appear to be proprietary and specific to users working at Google.

I am hoping to find users groups within Google that are part of the StackOverflow community.

I am specifically trying to use Dremel SQL / Google SQL to pull from a column that holds an array of arrays and then separate the items.  So far none of the SQL I have found online for any version of SQL uses the syntax, etc. that I am trying to use.

Answer (score 2):

- If you have on-topic question about technology - just ask. That's probably the easiest way to find out.
- Check if there are tags that looks like names of tools/frameworks you are interested in (i.e. tag for [plx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plx) does not exist). Try combinations of terms too like google-sql, sql-google.
- Do you know names of people in the community you are looking for? You can look up if some of such users are present (preferably active) on SO.

  I.e. for C# you can try John Skeet as author of well known C# book - let's see if he is active on SO - https://www.bing.com/search?q=john%20skeet%20site%3Astackoverflow.com shows some questions and link to user profile. Indeed checking the profile we confirm that the user is the John Skeet we are after and he's somewhat active with 1Mil rep - so good chance that there is active C# community.
- Do you know what methods / specific terms / operators or any specific questions are likely to be asked - search for those and see if questions are routinely answered. Presence of a lot of un-answered questions on the topic indicates there is no active community for the topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I already did several searches.

These technologies appear to be proprietary and specific to users working at Google.

I am hoping to find users groups within Google that are part of the StackOverflow community.

I am specifically trying to use Dremel SQL / Google SQL to pull from a column that holds an array of arrays and then separate the items.  So far none of the SQL I have found online for any version of SQL uses the syntax, etc. that I am trying to use.